# banner image loads with bigger size on mobile devices

Tags: css

I'm using: https://ready.mobi for testing my website for all devices. I'm interested in correctly set the image on the header for the index.
Right now the image is **not** looking great in all devices. Also the blue and orange buttons are too close to each other, and the
image appears too big (you have to scroll to see it).

Current result:

I've set media queries to handle this. Apparently they are not working well.

https://ready.mobi/#1164495-2wd6 (enter here to check the site on different devices online)

[image]

Desired result:

https://ready.mobi/#1164490-t8g2 (enter here to check the site on different devices online)

[image]

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EzOONJ

```
.my_header_bg_color {

    /*background-color: #4FB99F;*/
    /*background-color: #00ADB5;*/
    /*background-color: #6BB983;*/
    background-color: #00AD80;

}

/* Standard media queries breakpoints */

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */
    .my_home_banner {
        bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 8%;
        z-index: -600;
    }

    .productos_finales_home img {

        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }


    .my_home_banner_image {

        bottom: 0;
        top: 0;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
        width: 60%;
        display: block;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: 165px;
    }

    /*.my_home_banner_image {*/
    /*display: none;*/
    /*}*/
    .my_home_banner_title {
        color: white;
        font-size: 36px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_subtitle {
        margin-top: 0%;
        padding-top: 0%;
    }

    .btn, h2, p {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }



    .btn-comentario {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #969696;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
        letter-spacing: 0;
        line-height: 1.2;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        -o-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, .09) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .09) 100%);
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        padding: 22px 30px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border: none;
    }


.my_home_banner_left {
    margin-left: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.stickers_referenciales {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}


}

@media (min-width: 481px) {
    /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */
    .my_home_banner {
        bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 8%;
        z-index: -600;
    }


    .my_home_banner_image {

        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: -0px;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        width: 40%;
        display: block;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: 185px;
    }


    .my_home_banner_title {
        color: white;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_subtitle {
        margin-top: 0%;
        padding-top: 0%;
    }

    .btn, h2, p {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .btn-comentario {
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .my_home_banner_left {
        margin-left: 20px;
        z-index: 100;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 641px) {
    /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */
    .my_home_banner {
        bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 8%;
        z-index: -600;
    }


    .my_home_banner_image {

        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: -0px;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        width: 70%;
    }


    .my_home_banner_title {
        color: white;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_subtitle {
        margin-top: 0%;
        padding-top: 0%;
    }

    .btn, h2, p {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .btn-comentario {
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .my_home_banner_left {
        margin-left: 20px;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .my_home_banner_lef_text {
        margin-left: 10px;
        z-index: 100;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 961px) {
    /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */
    .my_home_banner {
        bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 8%;
        z-index: -600;
    }


    .my_home_banner_image {

        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: -0px;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        width: 60%;
    }


    .my_home_banner_title {
        color: white;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_subtitle {
        margin-top: 0%;
        padding-top: 0%;
    }

    .btn, h2, p {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .btn-comentario {
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .my_home_banner_left {
        margin-left: 20px;
        z-index: 100;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
    /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */
    .my_home_banner {
        bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 8%;
        z-index: -600;
    }


    .my_home_banner_image {

        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: -0px;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        width: 55%;
    }


    .my_home_banner_title {
        color: white;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_subtitle {
        margin-top: 0%;
        padding-top: 0%;
    }

    .btn, h2, p {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .btn-comentario {
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .my_home_banner_left {
        margin-left: 20px;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .subscribe_field {
        width: 350px;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 1281px) {
    /* hi-res laptops and desktops */
    .my_home_banner {
        bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 8%;
        z-index: -600;
    }


    .my_home_banner_image {

        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: -0px;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        width: 50%;
    }

    /*.my_home_banner_image_left {*/
    /*display: none;*/
    /*}*/
    .my_home_banner_title {
        color: white;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_subtitle {
        margin-top: 0%;
        padding-top: 0%;
    }

    .btn, h2, p {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .btn-comentario {
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .my_home_banner_left {
        margin-left: 20px;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .subscribe_field {
        width: 350px;
    }
}


.center-video {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
```

in place of:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In the html, you can specify different images for different size devices:

```
<picture>
   <source media="(max-width: 480px)" srcset="yoursourceMobile.jpg">
   <source media="(max-width: 2056px)" srcset="yoursource.jpg">
   <img src="yoursource.jpg">
</picture>
```